# Proving a case of the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'd like to prove the following lemma:

> *Lemma*: Let a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and suppose $f(a)<0<f(b)$. Then, there exists a $c\in(a,b)\ni f(c)=0$.

My attempt at the proof:

I will define $S=\{x\in [a,b]\ni f(x)\leq0\}.$ I will then let $c=\sup S$, which exists because $a\in S$ (so $S$ is non-empty) and because $S$ is bounded above (by $b$). I claim $f(c)=0$. I will prove this by showing that both $f(c)>0$ and $f(c)<0$ are not possible.

Suppose $f(c)<0$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U(c,\epsilon)$ such that $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in U\cap[a,b]$. Now, $c\neq b$, since $f(c)<0<f(b)$then. So it follows that there exists a point $p$ in $U$, such that $c<p<b$. Also, note that $f(p)\neq 0$ because $p\in U$. Also note that $p\in S$; this means that $c$ is not an upper bound of $S$, which contradicts our assumption that $c=\sup S$, as $c$ is not an upper bound.

Now let's suppose $f(c)>0$. Then there exists a neighborhood $V(c,\epsilon)$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in V\cap [a,b]$. Now $c\neq a$, as since $f(a)<0<f(c)$. It then follows that there exists a point $q$ in $V$ such that $a<q<c$. Because $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $V$, none of the points in $S$ are in $[q,c]$. This means that both $q$ and $c$ are upper bounds of $S$. But then $c$ is not the supremum of $S$. Contradiction.

Thus, $f(c)=0$. Since $f(a)<0<f(b)$, it follows that $c\in(a,b)$.

$\square$

Is the above valid (and are there any suggestions for improvement)?

Comment: sounds good to me. Don't know how you introduced the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ but if you said that every non-empty, bounded set does have a supremum the proof is correct

Comment: This seems fine. You may want to add a couple of words explaining why there is such a neighborhood $U(c,\epsilon)$ (or $V(c,\epsilon)$), since this is key to the whole argument.